# Multiple composite index vs single non-clustered column store index

Tags: sql-server, non-clustered-index, columnstore, indexed-view, azure-sql-managed-instance

We have a OLTP system and we have got a grid, which is containing close to 20 columns, coming from multiple tables. The grid loaded based on search parameters involving around 6 columns. The data is huge with 100M rows coming from background tables.

To improve the performance of the grid loading, we have created indexed view with single unique clustered index. We are currently want to see how we can improve the performance of search parameters: `a,b,c,d,e,f`

> The search can be based on any of the combination: (a), (a,c),(d,e), (a,b,c) ... (a,b,c,d,e,f)

We are thinking of either going for one of the below options:

- Multiple composite indexes on indexed view with specific access patterns like (a,b), (b,d), (a,b,c) etc.
- Single non-clustered columnstore index on indexed view, which will be helpful to satisfy all different access patterns  like (a,b), (b,d), (a,b,c) etc. with included column of 20 columns

Can you please suggest, which is better approach ?

**UPDATE**: Just read that, non-clustered column store index does not support include columns. Will try further and update the answer, either by comments, if question is closed or by answering it.

Comment: You have your actual data, an ability to implement the alternatives and to *measure* them against the actual querying patterns that matter to you. Why do you think strangers on the internet with none of those things will be able to give you a definitive answer?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I Agree with you. I was not sure whether non-clustered column store index will support different search patterns. As this is huge amount of data, wanted to get some options, before actually trying out. You are right. Will try it with data and update this question with answer.

Comment: None of the above because there are just too many options to consider, you would need a lot of indexes. At the most I would do single or two column indexes (depending how selective the first column is) for a few popular columns, anything wider is a waste of time, because you're going to need key lookups anyway. You should also consider something like `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` on your query

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks. Keylookup is happening now also, as we are pulling ~20 columns from the the indexed view

Comment: See also [#BackToBasics: An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Comment: @Charlieface, can you please add this as an answer, I will accept the same. We are  already doing dynamic sql only. We will try to add specific indexes for pattern and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are so many combinations to consider, you would need a lot of indexes.

So, at the most, I would do single or two column indexes (depending how selective the first column is) for a few popular columns. Anything wider is a waste of time, because the index will be selective either way.

**You most definitely *can* do `INCLUDE` columns on non-clustered indexes.** In this instance, it's only worth it if there are just those columns brought back, otherwise key lookups will be necessary in any case.

You should also consider something like `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on your query. See [#BackToBasics: An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) by Aaron Bertrand.